# how to combine 2 db calls into one

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How to combine below 2 db calls to one .Is it possible ?

```
IEnumerable<int> NewIds= Table1.NewValue.Split(',')
  .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out int num))
  .Select(int.Parse)
  .ToList();

if (NewIds!= null && NewIds.Count() > 0)
{
   NewValue = string.Join(",", _context.table1.Where(x => NewIds.Contains(x.Id))
                                              .Select(x => TempTextHelper.L(x.Name)));
}

IEnumerable<int> oldIds = Table1.OldValue.Split(',')
  .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out int num))
  .Select(int.Parse)
  .ToList();

if (oldIds != null && oldIds.Count() > 0)
{
    OldValue = string.Join(",", _context.table1.Where(x => oldIds.Contains(x.Id))
                                        .Select(x => TempTextHelper.L(x.Name)));
}
```

Thanks And Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid logic duplication create a method which gets ids from string value.
Also you can avoid parsing each string twice with aggregating parse results to hash set. Nice way to do it is an extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static HashSet<int> GetIds(this string value) =>
          value.Split(',').Aggregate(new HashSet<int>(),
              (acc, s) => { if (Int32.TryParse(s, out int x)) acc.Add(x); return acc; });
}
```

Also I would add second helper method to the same class (see usage later):

```
public static string CreateValue(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> items) =>
  String.Join(',', items.Select(kvp => TempTextHelper.L(kvp.Value)));
```

Now get all ids and query everything but include also Id into results:

```
var newIds = Table1.NewValue.GetIds();
var oldIds = Table1.OldValue.GetIds();
var ids = newIds.Union(oldIds).ToList(); // combine two sets of ids
if (ids.Any())
{
    // Single DB call
    var allResults = 
      _context.table1.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);

    NewValue = allResults.Where(kvp => newIds.Contains(kvp.Key)).CreateValue();
    OldValue = allResults.Where(kvp => oldIds.Contains(kvp.Key)).CreateValue();
}
```

Comment: THanks will try it

Comment: @user13656520 I added one more helper method and simple getting id-name entries as a dictionary. Check the updates